# Empty radio input validation

Tags: php

I have a form that contains radio input. The radio input can be either 0, 1 or enot chosen. I'm trying to do input validation to make sure that the values are only 0,1 or empty before they're posted to the database. Somehow the following code doesn't work.

Can somebody help me out?

```
$posttodatabase = true;
$array = (0, 1);
if (!in_array($_POST['x'], $array) && isset($_POST['x'])) {
    $posttodatabase = false;
};
```

EDIT: the attached form:

```
        <form action='registration.php' method=POST>
          <input type="radio" name="x" value=0> Foo
          <input type="radio" name="x" value=1> Bar
          <input class="button" type=submit value='Submit'>
        </form>
```

Comment: update your question to include the html/form.

Comment: you should quote everything in the form, that may be working against you. In either case, you've a few answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `$posttodatabase` default to `true` and change it to `false` when the requirements are not met. Use it the other way around to make sure the value is only set to `true` when the requirements are met (value exists and is one of the expected values).

```
$posttodatabase = false;
if (!isset($_POST['x']) OR                  // is not set OR
    (
        isset($_POST['x']) AND              // is set and...
        in_array($_POST['x'], array(0, 1))  // ... one of these values
    )) {
    $posttodatabase = true;
}
```

(or assign the value directly...)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't catch the empty radio value (which occurs when no option is specified). How do I solve this?

Comment: @StudentAsker Having no selection made is a valid option/"input"?

Comment: @StudentAsker Added the "not set" case to the if statement